# How to loop MoveTowards?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In mini game what I'm working on in Unity I want to loop movetowards. I want to move object and back to 1st position but not only 1 time. Now I have this code what give me working "move to postition and back system". How can I change this code to make loop in moving?

```
public class TestMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3;
    public Vector3 target = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 origin;

    void Start(){
        origin = transform.position;
    }

    void Update(){
        TestTransform ();
    }


    void TestTransform (){
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position == target) target = origin;
    }
}
```

Comment: when the transform gets to target, just check if the target is the origin. if so, set it to your destination, else set it to origin.
p.s.
you souldn't compare 2 vectors like that because float values might not be exactly the same. instead use distance calculation or something

Answer (score 2):

TestTransform is getting called from Update, meaning it gets called once for every frame. So, you are essentially already in a loop (an endless loop as long as your game is running). Let's look at your existing code and your desired outcome:
Your existing code starts immediately moving toward the target.  Upon reaching the target, it switches the target back to the origin, and starts moving back toward this new target.

Your code is *changing* the "target" to origin on the first pass.  After that, once it has returned to the new "target" (which is now "origin"), it's just sitting there, testing that transform.position == target, and setting target = origin over and over on every frame.

If you want the object to bounce back and forth between origin and target, there are a couple of changes you need to make:

1. You need a third Vector3 (let's call it "currentTarget").
2. On start, set currentTarget = target.
3. In TestTransform, change where you're testing against and changing "target" to operate on "currentTarget" instead.  When you change it, you'll need to consider whether currentTarget is set to target or origin, and pick the other as your next target.

End result should be "currentTarget" changes back and forth between "target" and "origin".

Side note: as someone else mentioned in comment, testing for exact equality of vectors won't always work -- you should be checking the distance between vectors and waiting for it to be less than some very small value.

Answer (score 2):

this alow you to have as many positions to move as you want, just create empty GameObjects for each target and add them to list in inspector. Your transform will move in loop, of course if you want only 2 positions add 2 elements to list. (ps. i added everything in your script just to make it easy to understand, i would recomend to make another method CheckNextPosition() with the logic that manages targets)

```
   public class TestMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 3;
        public List<Transform> targets= new List<Transform();
        public Transform target;
        protected int currentTargetIndex=0;


        void Start(){
            origin = transform.position;
            target= targets[currentTargetIndex];
        }

        void Update(){
            TestTransform ();
        }


        void TestTransform (){
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position == target.position)//check if you reached the target
        {            
            if(currentTargetIndex >= targets.Count)//check if you reached the last position in your targets list
            {
               currentTargetIndex=0;//go to first target in your target list
            }
            else
            {
               currentTargetIndex++;// go to next target in your target list
            }
            target=targets[currentTargetIndex];// set the next target
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: you can use an array which is more efficient, and calculate the next index with modulu sign:
currentTargetIndex = (currentTargetIndex+1)%targets.count;

Comment: It works fine but I have a small problem. When the object is moving between 2 positions (I created 2 empty targets objects) it gives me "Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: is your list.count== 2? check it in inspector. with 2 positions you should have currentIndex equa onlyl to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mathf.PingPong to easily do oscillation.

```
float distanceBetweenPosts = Vector3.Distance(origin, target);

float distanceTowardTarget = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, distanceBetweenPosts);

float percentageDistance = distanceTowardTarget / distanceBetweenPosts;

Vector3 currentOffset = (target-origin ) * percentageDistance;

Vector3 currentPosition = origin + currentOffset;

transform.position = currentPosition;
```

If you want to set a specific time `startTime` for the target starting at `origin`, then you can use :

```
float distanceTowardTarget = Mathf.PingPong((Time.time-startTime) * speed, 
                                            distanceBetweenPosts);
```